# Segmentation fault to sum an array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run a simple code in C++, that let the user enter an array of numbers and returns the sum of numbers in the array.
and that was the code:

```
int main() {

    int t;
    int arr[t];
    int sum=0;
    cin>> t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
      cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(int y=0;y<t;y++){
      sum+=arr[y];
    }
    cout<<sum;

    return 0;
}
```

I got a segmentation fault. any clarifications?

Comment: Uninitialized t, indexing out-of-bounds....

Comment: The `t` variable contents are undefined when you declare the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should change order of lines here:

```
int t;
cin>> t;
int arr[t];
int sum=0;
```

and better use `std::vector<int> arr(t);` for portability

Comment: This assumes variable length arrays which are not part of C++.  Try using dynamic memory allocation or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `std::vector` instead of arrays, because it can grow dynamically.
2. If you want to create arrays whose size is determined at run-time, use `new` as in:

   unsigned int t = 0;
     cin >> t;
     int * p_array = new int[t];

   Remember to use `delete [];` when you are done with the array.